# How to delete all children in a foreign key relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables in my database USERS, and USER_SESSIONS.  USER_SESSIONS has a foreign key on userid that maps to the USERS table's userid, and I have defined the many-to-one relationship in hibernate with:

```
<many-to-one name="user" column="USERID" class="com.Users" />
```

How do I write a hibernate method to delete all rows in the USER_SESSIONS database for a given user when only given the username.

My first attempt was to load the user object for the given username, and then do an HSQL to delete all sessions for that user's userid.  Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Do you want to delete all children even though parent row still exists?

Comment: You can delete records using HQL: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct. Use a query like `delete UserSession us where us.User = :user`. That said, if you're also deleting the owning `User`, it's better to cascade.

Comment: @Sajit Yes I'd like the user's to stay, but I want to delete all their sessions.  For instance, when a user logs out I want to logout all of their sessions which in this case involves removing the rows from the database.  I hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one other way could be as:

1. Define cascade as `delete` on the relationship
2. Load user entity
3. Remove all the user session object from user
4. Save user entity back.

Comment: This would work, but the User entity doesn't know about their Sessions.  It's not a bi-direction many-to-one relationship.

Comment: In that case, HQL `(delete UserSession u where u.User = :user)` is the option.